# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{2n\choose n}\frac{1}{8^n}=\sqrt {2}$

Tags: summation

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\begin{pmatrix}2n\\ n\end{pmatrix}\:\frac{1}{8^n}=\sqrt{2}$$ I know that I should use some Taylor series, but which one I'm not sure.

Comment: MathJax tip: '{n \choose k}' also gives you ${n \choose k}$

Comment: You can get genuine binomial coefficients using either `{n \choose k}` or `\binom{n}{k}`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is known that

$$\left ( 1-4 x^2 \right )^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2 n}{n} x^{2 n} $$

Plug in $x^2=\frac18$.